# Qt connect crash when using lambda function

Tags: qt, lambda

Code is here

```
void A::fun()
{
    QAction* act = new QAction(this);
    QAction* act2 = new QAction(this);
    connect(act, QAction::triggered, [this, &act2]() {...; act2.setDisable(true);}
                              // crash when &act2 is used to capture the variable
                              // but it is okay using act2 to capture the variable
}
```

What is the reason? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are taking a *reference* of `act2` even though it is a pointer that will go out scope, that is why copying the pointer works.

Comment: It crashes other than gives a compilation error. And why go out of scope? Thanks.

Comment: The _object_ at `act2` does not go out of scope (it's on the heap), but the variable `act2` is only in scope in `fun()`.